# Finding word permutations in text

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to find words for a text file that have the same number of characters but are in a different order. For example. I input a word like "hyone" and I want to find a word with the same length and number of characters from the text file. In this case "honey" or "heony".

I have already tried using grep with regex but the code I used returns words that are the same length but don't have the same number of characters.

I used this command:

> grep -E "^[hyone]{5}$" list.txt

This command return words that are 5 characters long but they include the words that are not made with all of the characters like "hoooo" or "yeehe".
Please note that the examples given are made up but they summarize the problem.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a task for regex. I think you want to read about `Levenshtein distance`.

Answer (score 2):

not the best-looking regexp but for your example it's working:

```
\b(?=.*h)(?=.*y)(?=.*o)(?=.*n)(?=.*e).{5}\b
```

This one checks if 5 signs (change `.` to `\w` for characters and digits only or use `[a-z]` for ASCII) are preceeded by the chars h, y, o, n, and e.

It might not work on other examples, though. And for usage as one-liner its creation could be a bit tricky for other characters to be checked for. So, regexps might not be the best solution for such problems. Levenshtein (as suggested by Thomas; maybe in addition to Soundex) could work a lot better - they are a bit more complicated, however

You can test the given regexp online at: https://regex101.com/r/7Cdu03/3/

Comment: A more [visual presentation](https://regexper.com/#%5Cb%28%3F%3D.*h%29%28%3F%3D.*y%29%28%3F%3D.*o%29%28%3F%3D.*n%29%28%3F%3D.*e%29.%7B5%7D%5Cb) of your regular expression.